# Selectize appendValue instead of setValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

unable to insert multiple items in selectize select box using below given code currently i am trying to insert multiple items in selectize select box but fail

```
           var $select = $('#input-tags3').selectize({

                                    persist: false,
                                    create: true
                                });

                 var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
                selectize.clear();
                var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
                for ( var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ) {

                selectize.setValue(selectize.search(shan[i]).items[0].id);
```

i want to add multiple values so i need function like appendValue() so i will be able to add multiple values dynamically using script in my select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addItem(value, silent)](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_items) function to append new values.